# Проблема с отладчиком в Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка

Запускаю отладку приложения, возникает следующая ситуация:

[image]

В окне Debugger ничего не выводится:
[image: g]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже раньше видел. Причина джава 12+

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205486/how-to-avoid-sharing-is-only-supported-for-boot-loader-classes-because-bootstra

[image]

Comment: Теперь работает, спасибо)